# Simpson's rule, declaration of user requested input not accepted? fortran

Tags: variables, fortran, integration

I'm working on this problem of getting the area under a tan curve using Simpson's rule. However, I keep getting errors I don't understand - even on different compilers like gfortran and ifort.

I realize that I could make pi a parameter in the main body of the program, but I'd rather just find out where I'm going wrong. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
module consts

        !Declare pi as a global variable 
     real(4),parameter :: pi=3.1415927
end module


PROGRAM simpson
  use consts
  implicit none
  REAL :: area, h, sumo, sume
  INTEGER (kind=4) :: i, j, k !Loop index, Counter, Number of points
  REAL (kind=4) ::  rad, TanTab(0) !Radian variable to be calculated in Subroutine, Result array
!k = number of steps
   WRITE(6,*) "Please enter number of steps required (odd number)"
   READ(5,*) k

    IF(MOD(k,2) ==  1) THEN

CONTINUE
    ELSE
WRITE(*,*) "Hey, I said as an odd number"
    READ(5,*) k

    ENDIF


h = (60.0)/(k-1) ! Defining step size in relation to number of sampling points

 DO i=1,61,1
! Get table of tan
     call degtorad((i-1)*1.0, rad)

     TanTab(j) = tan(rad)

     j=j+1
    write(*,*) "Tan(", i, ")", TanTab(i)
    write(*,*) "Tan(", j, ")", TanTab(j)
 ENDDO

  DO j=1,k-1,h 
    IF(MOD(k,2) == 1) THEN
    sumo = sumo + TanTab(j)  !sum of odd functions
    ELSE
    sume = sume + TanTab(j)   !sum of even functions

    area = (h/3)*( (4*sumo) + (2*sume) + tan(1.047))
WRITE(6,*) area
    ENDIF
  ENDDO





END PROGRAM simpson
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: Your step size `h` is `real`! This could cause tremendous (and hard to find) errors. Please, only use `integer`s for loop counters... Also, take care about mixing `real`s and `integer`s (like in `h = (60.0)/(k-1)`) - this might not behave the way you intended it to.

Comment: did you write this yourself or is it a "find the bugs" homework problem?  Among  many issues, your final write will never be encountered because its inside `if k even` construct, while up top you (sort of try) to ensure k is odd.  Also why hard code 61 in the first loop?

Comment: Hi George, I wrote it myself - just working through some problems in a book so I used some snippets of code I had written in other problems. I obviously still have a lot to learn about mixing variables and I make simple mistakes like writing 1 instead of 1.0 when trying to use and operation with a real. I have learnt my lesson about using reals in loops now. Can anyone recommend a good debugger for fortran? I get source level bug info from my intel compiler, but there must be something more substantial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have more mistakes in your code:

- in calculation of h, you are using degs and not rads
- upper bound of integral connected to number of items in TanTab array
- not init variables to 0 (sumo, sume, ...)
- calculation of area for each step, could be done outside do loop
- out-of-bounds mistakes

You should start using debugger and learn how to find problems in your code. The working version is here:

```
  PROGRAM simpson
  implicit none
  REAL :: area, h, sumo, sume
  INTEGER (kind=4) :: i!Loop index
  integer, parameter :: k = 100
  REAL (kind=4) ::  rad, TanTab(k+1) !Radian variable to be calculated in Subroutine, Result array

  sumo = 0.0
  sume = 0.0
  area = 0.0
  h = 0.0174532925 * 60.0/real(k) ! Defining step size in relation to number of sampling points

  DO i=1,k+1
      rad = 0.0174532925 * 60.0 * real(i-1) /real(k)
      TanTab(i) = tan(rad)
      ! write(*,*) "Tan(", i-1, ")", TanTab(i)
  ENDDO

  DO i=2,k
      IF(MOD(i,2) == 1) THEN
        sumo = sumo + TanTab(i)  !sum of odd functions
      ELSE
        sume = sume + TanTab(i)  !sum of even functions
      ENDIF
  ENDDO

  ! by simson
  area = (h/3)*( TanTab(1) + (2*sume) + (4*sumo) + TanTab(k+1))
  WRITE(*,*) area

  ! by integration
  area = log(1.0) - log(cos(0.0174532925 * 60.0))
  WRITE(*,*) area
  END PROGRAM simpson
```

Comment: If you're going to post a *working version* why not post a good one ?.  Picking nits (i) `log(1.0)` is always `0` so why bother (ii) you've declared `k` real, then cast it ( `real(k)` ) a couple of times, and generally used it as if it were an `integer` (iii) constants such as `0.0174532925 * 60.0` are good candidates for declaration as parameters.  Possibly other issues too.

Comment: The code is working in terms that you get reasonable approximate of integral and it clearly shows all errors that were in original question. To your comment i) This is not a production code, but shows the math behind. Even log(1.0) is 0, it is more explanatory it terms of what is going on there ii) I had k declared as int (as in question) and forgot that I have changed that to real later on iii) same as i) it shows the deg->rad conversion explicitely, which is better for understanding the code.

Comment: It's nice to have the comparison between implementation by Simpson's rule and by integration for understanding. Good news is I understand what you wrote, which should help prevent me from putting up simple errors again.

Comment: @user3311029 I am happy that it has helped. Remember, when you write new code, it is always nice to find some way how to check that the code is doing its job correctly (it is called testing)

Answer (score 1):

I can see one probably cause of a crash at run time, sparking a segmentation violation:

You use `j` in the line

```
 TanTab(j) = tan(rad)
```

before you assign a value to it.  Fortran doesn't do any automatic initialisation of variables.

I can also see something very fishy.  You declare `tantab` to have dimension `0`:

```
 REAL (kind=4) ::  rad, TanTab(0)
```

Now Fortran will happily access elements of arrays outside their declared bounds and sometimes (sometimes for a very long time) the users of a program won't notice the problem.  If you compile your code with the option `-check bounds` (that's the Intel version, other compilers have the same facility, consult your documentation) and then try running your code you should get a run-time error.

And I agree with @AlexanderVogt (I usually do) about your use of a real variable for the loop index. Don't do that.

Comment: Thanks, I've declared it to have a dimension of 1 instead and assigned a value to j before the do loop but now, even though it is compiling, it does not print any results after I enter an odd number for the input?

Comment: Giving `TanTab` a dimension of `1` is just as wrong as giving it a dimension of `0` when it is clear from your code that you want to create a table of values of tangents.  Why are you not declaring the array to have either the right size or to have a size which can be set at run time ?  I won't be commenting again.  If you want further input, edit your question to reflect your updated issues.  And, for Knuth's sake, tell us exactly what error messages or aberrant behaviour you are experiencing.

Comment: Grand, it isn't spitting out any errors anymore, it just quits while running after asking for input and allowing me to enter it- as just stated. I'm confused about the notion of dimensions, I try 2 for a table, I try 62 for the number of steps - same problem each time. I don't have to do this for anything, apart from my own learning so no worries and thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to think about: The loop `DO i=1,61,1` suggests that you should be setting `TanTab(i)`, not `TanTab(j)`. Why bother with the additional variable `j` that increments as `i` does?   And since the loop goes from 1 to 61 suggests that you should declare `TanTab` as `real, dimension (1:61) :: TabTab`, otherwise its not going to be large enough to store the values.   But then your next loop, `DO j=1,k-1,h` is different.   Are you sure that it is accessing `TabTab (j)` in a consistent manner?

Comment: Ah, it hadn't occurred to be that my use of 'j' was redundant because I was partially translating an old code I wrote in C for a similar task.